# Stripe Try/Catch block returning 500 for AJAX request in Laravel 5

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have been struggling with getting the Stripe card errors to work properly with my AJAX call. Instead of returning some nice JSON, it is returning a 500 error. Of course, I need to be able to display the error for the user to see. I'm not sure if this is Laravel specific so I thought that was worth mentioning. Here is my try/catch block:

```
public function charge($type, $amount, $isSubscription = false)
    {
        try {
            Charge::create([
                'amount' => $amount,
                'currency' => 'usd',
                'description' => $type,
                'customer' => $this->customer['id'],
            ]);
        } catch (\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
            $body = $e->getJsonBody();
            dd($body); // This does not work
        }
```

It seems like I never reach the `dd()` block of code, but instead I get a `500` in the console and when I preview the error, it is in html like the Laravel exceptions. I have tried using `echo json_encode()` to return the error, but again, if I'm not even getting to the `dd()` part, then it makes sense I would never reach `echo json_encode`.

Here is my AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    _.showSuccess();
    _.clearForm();
  },
  error: function (response) {
    _.hideSubmitProcessing();
    console.log(response); // This is returning html and a 500 in the console
  }
});
```

Here is a screenshot of the error in the console:
[image]

I've been looking at this for too long and def need another set of eyes to help me out.

Comment: debug it step by step. First, dd($type) and then dd($amount) before the try block. Then, if they are passed. try to create a charge without try/catch and so go on

Comment: Is Charge a model, a Facade, something else? What is the code for this `create` method on `Charge` class?

Comment: @El_Matella Charge is a Stripe class. I'm using their PHP client.

Comment: Didn't you forget a `;` after the `dd($body)` ? Does a `dd('Hello World')` works before the `$body = $e->getJsonBody();` ? Is this an exact copy paste? I read the code of the Stripe lib, nothing seems wrong

Comment: @El_Matella I noticed I forgot the comma but I added it and it gives me the error in the screenshot. It's throwing the exception correctly, but I'm not sure how to get that back as my AJAX response. I'm thinking it may be Laravel specific. Could be wrong.

Comment: And what happens when you `dd('hello world');` before the `$body = $e->getJsonBody();` ?

Comment: @El_Matella The same thing happens. Actually, even if I remove the `try` `catch` block and wrap the `Charge::create` method within a `dd()`, it still does the same thing. It doesn't seem like it should return a 500 error.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, here's the fix if anyones still looking for it:

**\Stripe\Exception\CardException**
- this is now used as the main exception for any stripe card exception.

```
 } catch (\Stripe\Exception\CardException $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 5,
            'message' => $e->getMessage()
        ]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 5,
            'message' => $e->getMessage()
        ]);
    }
```